# New wifi card is not recognized. Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, iwlwifi

I got a new network card (Intel Wireless-AC 9260) for my Dell XPS 13 running Ubuntu 16.04. The problem is that the new network card is not working. The lshw command shows that it is unclaimed. The old network card is still working, when switching back.

I updated the kernel for the firmware and also tried a lot of other things suggested in other threads. What I notized is that when I use modinfo iwlwifi that the firmware of my card is not listed, but the files are in the lib/firmware folder. I do not know if this is the problem.

So I am glad for any help!

Also I post some command outputs requested in other threads in case they help.

**uname -a:**

```
Linux xxx-XPS-13-9360 4.4.0-174-generic #204-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 29 06:41:01 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**sudo lshw -C network:**

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless-AC 9260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
       version: 29
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:dc200000-dc203fff
```

**modinfo iwlwifi:**

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-174-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-13.ucode
srcversion:     CB5AC244E1344F14798FC7E
```

**ls /lib/firmware/ | grep 9260:**

```
iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-33.ucode
iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode
iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode
```

Comment: Try booting from a 19.10 LiveUSB.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I tried the USB and it worked. I also looked into modinfo and the firmware for the is loaded. Do you know how I can fix this with Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Thanks to user chili555! The linked question solved my issue.